# Infinite axiom schemas - what comes before?

Tags: axioms, foundations

The ZFC axioms constitute an infinite set. So too do the PA axioms. Presumably, then, we need a metatheory before we can even *define* these axiom systems.

What is the usual metatheory?

Do we even need one?

Answer (score 0):

We don't define ZFC as a *set* of axioms in some metatheory. This basically works like this: for every ZFC axiom, we write a sequence of symbols on a sheet of paper, and say that these are "theorems" of ZFC. For axiom schema, instead of a single axiom, we write the rule "if you take any formula (usually subject to some constraints), and substitute it for $\phi$ in this following axiom schema, it will constitute a theorem of ZFC". Then, we introduce some rules that allow us to infer new "theorems" of ZFC from the ones we already know (the axioms). Then we say that a "theorem" of ZFC is a sequence of symbols that can be derived from "axioms" by a finitely many applications of the inference rules.

There's no metatheory. There are no sets. It's only rewriting symbols on a sheet of paper according to some rules.

Now, you can interpret the statements and rules inside some other (or even the same) theory, but this is only a mirror of the term rewriting process.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, but I want to know more. What is the language that the rewriting rules are written in?

Comment: English. Or other native language.

Comment: Surely they're written in a precise specification language?

Comment: They are written so that human can easily understand it, and easily tell the difference between correct and incorrect application of rules.